# Integer.parseInt number format exception?

Tags: java, radix

I feel like I must be missing something simple, but I am getting a `NumberFormatException` on the following code:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("howareyou",35))
```

**[Ideone](http://ideone.com/3Q1h5d)**

It can convert the String `yellow` from base 35, I don't understand why I would get a `NumberFormatException` on this String.

Comment: From the documentation: "Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument. The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned. "

Comment: The number produced is too large for a java Integer, use a Long...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because the result will get greater than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Try this

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("yellow", 35));
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("howareyou", 35));
```

and for

```
Long.parseLong("abcdefghijklmno",25)
```

you need [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Try this and you will see why

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(new BigInteger("abcdefghijklmno",25));
```

Comment: This seems to be correct. However, I have hit a new problem of `Long.parseLong("abcdefghijklmno",25)`. Any idea on how I can parse larger numbers since is no parseBigDecimal?

Comment: @Danny, For that you need, `BigInteger big=new BigInteger("abcdefghijklmno", 25);`

Answer (score 5):

From the JavaDocs:

> An exception of type `NumberFormatException` is thrown if any of the following situations occurs:
>
> - The first argument is `null` or is a string of length zero. **FALSE: "howareyou" is not `null` and over 0 length**
> - The radix is either smaller than `Character.MIN_RADIX` or larger than `Character.MAX_RADIX`. **FALSE: 35 is in range [2,36]**
> - Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix, except that the first character may be a minus sign '-' ('\u002D') or plus sign '+' ('\u002B') provided that the string is longer than length 1. **FALSE: all characters of "howareyou" are in radix range [0,'y']**
> - **==>** The value represented by the string is not a value of type `int`. **TRUE: The reason for the exception. The value is too large for an `int`.**

Either `Long` or `BigInteger` should be used

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, you just dump 4 options without making clear which one is the cause (and why).

Comment: Shotgun approach is still wrong here.  There is one and only one correct answer.  Just because you added it in with 3 others that are completely wrong doesn't make your answer right.

Comment: @DavidMays The first were obviously false to me - so quoting the full java docs should have helped if the OP used process of elimination - but edited for clarity now

Answer (score 5):

Could it be that the number is > `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? If I try your code with `Long` instead, it works.

Answer (score 5):

The number is getting bigger than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("yellow", 35));
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("howareyou", 35));
```

As seen in René Link comments you are looking for something like this using a [BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219894/integer-parseint-number-format-exception/20220061#20220045):

```
BigInteger big=new BigInteger("abcdefghijklmno", 25);
```

Something like this:

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(new BigInteger("abcdefghijklmno",25));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, you're running out of space in your `Integer`. By swapping it out for a `Long`, you get the desired result. [Here is the IDEOne Link to the working code](http://ideone.com/ASJQI8).

**Code**

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("YELLOW",35));
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("HOWAREYOU",35));
```

Answer (score 2):

The number produced is too large for a Java Integer, use a Long.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers of parseLong would be correct, but sometime that is also not large enough so the other option would to use a BigInteger.

```
Long.parseLong("howareyou", 35)
new BigInteger("howareyou", 35)
```